# DHTMLX Error on dock [ing] an undocked cell

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I am having trouble getting an undocked cell in DHTMLX 4 to dock.

When I click on the provided "dock" button(on the undocked cell) I get the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null`

I also get this same error when assigning the `.dock()` function to another button.

> onclick: function ()
>   {
>
> ```
> // where to undock to
> _this.dhxLayout.dhxWins.attachViewportTo("layout_div");
>
> // init & undock window
> var popup_cell = _this.dhxLayout.cells("c");
> popup_cell.undock(0,0,800,600);
>
> var popup_window = _this.dhxLayout.dhxWins.window("c");
> popup_window.button("minmax1").hide();
> popup_window.setText(" ");
>
> // things to do when window is opened
> popup_cell.attachEvent("onUnDock", alert("undocked"));
>
> // assigning .dock() to another button, neither work
> popup_window.button("park").attachEvent("onClick", function(popup_window){_this.dhxLayout.cells("c").dock();});
> // popup_window.button("park").attachEvent("onClick", function(popup_window){popup_cell.dock()});
>
>  }
> ```

The traceback takes me to `c=this.layout.dhxWins.window(this.conf.name);c.close();` so I am guessing that `c` is somehow undefined? Is there an argument/parameter I am supposed to be passing in the `.dock(foo)`? The API shows no examples with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed out on this: http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=37052

And followed it to change the offending line of:
`c=this.layout.dhxWins.window(this.conf.name);c.close();`

(in dhtmlx.js)
to

`c=g.dhxWins.window(this.conf.name);c.close();`

and the problem is fixed!